# Tiles won't parse Struts tags

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, tiles

I'm tried using tiles but it seems that it's not parsing the Struts tags, It outputs them directly e.g.  instead of ...
What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the taglib library header in each JSP file, regardless of whether it's a tile or not:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
```

etc...

Without this the tags will not be parsed.

Comment: +1 for reminding me how stupid Struts 1 is (coming from both ASP.NET/MVC and Rails).  NOW it renders the tags in my tiles.  Jeesh.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen evaluation-order things with netsed tags in jsp's - you're likely to run into problems with things like

```
 <t:x name="<c:out ...
```

Can you post code and output? (I'm guessing you're code got parsed out because you didn't use the nice binary-logo button)